# JBossFuse IllegalArgumentException in CXF Client

Tags: apache-camel, cxf, redhat, jbossfuse

I'm getting a rather odd exception in a camel route. It is comparing a class with itself and identifying them as different types. I can only assume is the result of a ClassLoader issue.  This is the exception formatted for clarity (full trace to below).

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
    Part {http://ws.someco.com/messageserv}createMsgRequest 
    should be of type 
        com.someco.ws.messageserv.CreateMsgRequest, 
    not com.someco.ws.messageserv.CreateMsgRequest
```

Can anyone suggest a solution?

These are some of the version detail:

```
JBoss Fuse (6.2.1.redhat-084)

[installed  ] [2.15.1.redhat-621084 ] camel-cxf                                     camel-2.15.1.redhat-621084           
[installed  ] [1.2.0.redhat-621084  ] fabric-cxf                                    fabric-1.2.0.redhat-621084           
[installed  ] [3.0.4.redhat-621084  ] cxf-specs                                     cxf-3.0.4.redhat-621084              
[installed  ] [3.0.4.redhat-621084  ] cxf-core                                      cxf-3.0.4.redhat-621084              
[installed  ] [3.0.4.redhat-621084  ] cxf-wsdl                                      cxf-3.0.4.redhat-621084              
[installed  ] [3.0.4.redhat-621084  ] cxf-http                                      cxf-3.0.4.redhat-621084              
[installed  ] [3.0.4.redhat-621084  ] cxf-http-jetty                                cxf-3.0.4.redhat-621084              
[installed  ] [3.0.4.redhat-621084  ] cxf-bindings-soap                             cxf-3.0.4.redhat-621084              
[installed  ] [3.0.4.redhat-621084  ] cxf-jaxws                                     cxf-3.0.4.redhat-621084              
[installed  ] [3.0.4.redhat-621084  ] cxf-jaxrs                                     cxf-3.0.4.redhat-621084              
[installed  ] [3.0.4.redhat-621084  ] cxf-databinding-jaxb                          cxf-3.0.4.redhat-621084
```

This is from the logged error

```
2016-09-28 15:18:44,541 | ERROR | tp1704597020-170 | DefaultErrorHandler              | 198 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.15.1.redhat-621084 | Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-IFDS3854-57235-1475090154837-1-1 on ExchangeId: ID-IFDS3854-57235-1475090154837-1-2). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Part {http://ws.someco.com/messageserv}createMsgRequest should be of type com.someco.ws.messageserv.CreateMsgRequest, not com.someco.ws.messageserv.CreateMsgRequest

Message History
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
[route2            ] [route2            ] [cxf://bean:msgservpocEndpoint                                                 ] [       256]
[route2            ] [removeHeaders2    ] [removeHeaders[*]                                                              ] [         1]
[route2            ] [log4              ] [log                                                                           ] [         1]
[route2            ] [to3               ] [ref:createMsgReqTransformer                                                   ] [        97]
[route2            ] [process2          ] [ref:imageProcessor                                                         ] [         0]
[route2            ] [setHeader2        ] [setHeader[operationName]                                                      ] [         0]
[route2            ] [log5              ] [log                                                                           ] [         1]
[route2            ] [messageservEndpoin] [cxf:bean:messageservEndpoint?defaultOperationName=createMsg&defaultOperationNa] [       152]

Exchange
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exchange[
    Id                  ID-IFDS3854-57235-1475090154837-1-2
    ExchangePattern     InOut
    Headers             {CamelRedelivered=false, CamelRedeliveryCounter=0, operationName=createMsg}
    BodyType            java.util.ArrayList
    Body                [com.someco.ws.messageserv.CreateMsgRequest@161e2951]
]

Stacktrace
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Part {http://ws.someco.com/messageserv}createMsgRequest should be of type com.someco.ws.messageserv.CreateMsgRequest, not com.someco.ws.messageserv.CreateMsgRequest
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataWriterImpl.checkPart(DataWriterImpl.java:292)[79:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:3.0.4.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataWriterImpl.write(DataWriterImpl.java:220)[79:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:3.0.4.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.writeParts(AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.java:122)[74:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.0.4.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.interceptors.BareOutInterceptor.handleMessage(BareOutInterceptor.java:69)[78:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-wsdl:3.0.4.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)[74:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.0.4.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:516)[74:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.0.4.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:418)[74:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.0.4.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfProducer.process(CxfProducer.java:116)[207:org.apache.camel.camel-cxf:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:139)[198:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)[198:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:448)[198:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)[198:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:121)[198:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)[198:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)[198:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfConsumer$1.asyncInvoke(CxfConsumer.java:95)[207:org.apache.camel.camel-cxf:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfConsumer$1.invoke(CxfConsumer.java:75)[207:org.apache.camel.camel-cxf:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)[74:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.0.4.redhat-621084]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)[:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)[:1.7.0_79]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$2.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:126)[74:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.0.4.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)[74:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.0.4.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:131)[74:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.0.4.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)[74:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.0.4.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)[74:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.0.4.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:251)[96:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.0.4.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.doService(JettyHTTPDestination.java:261)[205:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty:3.0.4.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPHandler.handle(JettyHTTPHandler.java:70)[205:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty:3.0.4.redhat-621084]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1088)[86:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1024)[86:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)[86:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)[86:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)[86:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)[86:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)[86:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:982)[86:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1043)[86:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)[86:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)[86:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)[86:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696)[86:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53)[86:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)[86:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)[86:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.7.0_79]
```

Comment: Looks like a XML name spacing issue.

"{http://ws.someco.com/messageserv}createMsgRequest" is fully qualified, where "createMsgRequest" is not

Comment: I don't see an XML namespace issue.It's resolving the correct JAXB class for the message.  But when it evaluates typeClass.isInstance(object) in line 291 of DataWriterImpl, false is returned even though object is nominally of that exact type. Which makes me think class loader.

Comment: Did you re-deploy your bundle inside fuse? (eg **dev:watch** on a maven url) If your application is split in two bundles (API + application) try manually issuing the **refresh** command.

Comment: That seemed to work. On to a different exception now. Thanks